# Is the assignment of exercised options "truly" random

Tags: options

Everyone seems to say that assignment of exercised options is random; does it just appear random to an outside viewer or does the exchange pick a name from hat for assignment?

Comment: Yes, the exchange uses a random number generator.

Comment: @AlexC Is there any available information about what kind of generator they use? Also, if you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exchange takes seriously its responsibility to assign exercises fairly. Typically it is a two stage process. The exchange uses a random number generator to assign the exercise among the brokerage firms they deal with. The brokerage firm is then responsible for assigning the exercise among its customers; generally they also use a random process. The exchange must approve and inspect the process used by the brokerage firm.

(I have never worked for an option exchange so I have no idea what kind of r.n.g. they use).

Comment: Based on the predictable bad luck I've had sometimes it feels like IBM's RANDU.